# Organize Azure Data Factory Objects in Git folders

Tags: azure-data-factory

Azure Data Factory supports organizing it's objects (Pipelines, datasets etc) into Folders with in the ADF Studio.

When the ADF is connected to a Git repository all the ADF Objects are moved into git based on the AD Component Type.

Below is how the Pipelines are organized with in the ADF Studio

[image]

After saving the changes, this is how the files are structure in the git

[image]

If I organize the P1-Pipeline.json and P2.Pipeline.json into separate folders with in git then the ADF Studio doesn't recognize them.

It is really important for us to organize the Pipelines (and other ADF Components) into folders within git as each Folder represent a separate team.

Is there a possibility to organize the ADF components into git folders? If not, what is the recommended approach for selective deployment of the ADF components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I organize the P1-Pipeline.json and P2.Pipeline.json into separate folders with in git then the ADF Studio doesn't recognize them.

No, you shouldn't change the location of the `pipeline.json` file to another folder in Git Repo. You should create any pipeline in a separate folder and if want to move it to another folder, move it in ADF Studio only.

By clicking on the three dots in front of the pipeline name, click on `Move item` option and then choose the folder in which you want to move the pipeline.

In the below example I have moved the pipeline1 from project1 folder to project2 folder.

[image]

And I can still see both the ARM files of these pipelines in Azure Repo.

**If you want to keep each pipeline in a separate folder, it’s better to create ARM template for each pipeline by clicking on `Save as template` option, refer below image.**

[image]

**Your each ARM template as json will be stored in separate sub-folder by pipeline name under main `templates` folder as shown in below image.**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation that we shouldn't change the git folder structure.

Comment: Are you saving pipeline as ARM template?

Comment: No. Not as ARM Template

Comment: Could you please try that. This will automatically arrange your json in repo.

Comment: We are not looking for saving them as ARM Templates.